# Strange behaviour with pointers in C (change values arbitrary)

Tags: c, pointers, hierarchical-clustering

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct point{
    int id;
    double* values;
};

struct cluster{
    int n_tot;
    int n_act;
    int *ids;
    double* values;
};

struct temp_cluster{
    int n;
    struct point *points;
    double* values;
};

struct compressed{
    int n_tot;
    int *ids;
    double* values;
};


#define randnum(min, max) ((rand() % (int)(((max) + 1) - (min))) + (min))

/**
 * Error code:
 * 11 bad parameters
 * 12 Memory allocation error
 * 13 File opening error
 */

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 6) {
        printf("Error parameters! Usage: ./main <input_file> <points_dimension> <cluster_number> <alpha> <threshold>");
        exit(11);
    }

    char *filename = argv[1];
    int dimension = atoi(argv[2]);
    int k = atoi(argv[3]);
    float alpha = atof(argv[4]);
    float threshold = alpha * atof(argv[5]);

    int idx;
    int elem_idx;
    double temp;
    double distance;
    double beta;
    int k_cs = 0;
    int processd_point;
    int chunk_size = 20;
    int pinr = 0;
    int k_cs_temp = 7;
    bool stop = false;


    struct compressed *compressed_set = NULL;
    struct point *retained_set = NULL;

    /** CHUNK READING **/

    struct point *dataset = malloc(chunk_size * sizeof(struct point));

    if (!dataset)
        exit(12);

    for (int i = 0; i < chunk_size; i++) {
        dataset[i].values = malloc(dimension * sizeof(double));
        if (!dataset[i].values)
            exit(12);
    }

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!file)
        exit(13);

    char *line = NULL, *token;
    size_t len = 0;

    idx = -1;
    elem_idx = -1;
    while ((getline(&line, &len, file)) != -1 && idx < chunk_size) {
        if (idx > -1) { //Ovvero salto la riga di intestazione
            while ((token = strsep(&line, ","))) {
                if (elem_idx == -1) //è l'id del punto
                    dataset[idx].id = atoi(token);
                else //sono i dati del punto
                    dataset[idx].values[elem_idx] = atof(token);
                elem_idx++;
            }
            elem_idx = -1;
            idx++;
        } else
            idx++;
    }
    fclose(file);
    processd_point = chunk_size;

    /** END **/


    /** CLUSTER INIZIALIZATION **/

    struct cluster *discard_set = malloc(k * sizeof(struct cluster));

    if (!discard_set)
        exit(12);

    /*
     * First centre is randomly chosen from the dataset. The following centres are chosen as the point that doesn't belong to previous
     * clusters
     */
    
    chunk_size--;

    srand(time(NULL));
    elem_idx = randnum(0, chunk_size);

    discard_set[0].n_tot = 1;
    discard_set[0].n_act = 1;

    discard_set[0].ids = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (!discard_set[0].ids)
        exit(12);
    discard_set[0].ids[0] = dataset[elem_idx].id;

    discard_set[0].values = malloc(dimension * sizeof(double));
    if (!discard_set[0].values)
        exit(12);

    for (int j = 0; j < dimension; ++j) {
        discard_set[0].values[j] = dataset[elem_idx].values[j];
        discard_set[0].values[j + dimension] = pow(dataset[elem_idx].values[j], 2);
    }

    /*
     * Deleting point chosen as a cluster centre from the dataset (I don't need to store it anymore)
    */

    free(dataset[elem_idx].values);
    if (elem_idx < chunk_size)
        memcpy(dataset + elem_idx, dataset + elem_idx + 1, (chunk_size - elem_idx) * sizeof(struct point));

    dataset = realloc(dataset, chunk_size * sizeof(struct point));
    if (!dataset)
        exit(12);

    /*
     * Next cluster centres
     */

    int pos;

    for (int i = 1; i < k; ++i) {

        for (int j = 0; j < chunk_size; ++j) {
            bool checked = true;

            for (int l = 0; l < i && checked; ++l) {
                temp = 0;

                for (int m = 0; m < dimension; ++m) {
                    temp += pow(discard_set[l].values[m] - dataset[j].values[m], 2);
                }
                distance = sqrt(temp);
                if (distance < threshold)
                    checked = false;
            }

            if (checked) {
                pos = j;
                break;
            }
        }

        chunk_size--;

        discard_set[i].n_tot = 1;
        discard_set[i].n_act = 1;

        discard_set[i].ids = malloc(sizeof(int));
        if (!discard_set[i].ids)
            exit(12);
        discard_set[i].ids[0] = dataset[pos].id;

        discard_set[i].values = malloc(dimension * sizeof(double));
        if (!discard_set[i].values)
            exit(12);

        for (int j = 0; j < dimension; ++j) {
            discard_set[i].values[j] = dataset[pos].values[j];
            discard_set[i].values[j + dimension] = pow(dataset[pos].values[j], 2);
        }

        free(dataset[pos].values);
        if (pos < chunk_size)
            memcpy(dataset + pos, dataset + pos + 1, (chunk_size - pos) * sizeof(struct point));
        dataset = realloc(dataset, chunk_size * sizeof(struct point));
        if (!dataset)
            exit(12);
    }

    /** ------END------- **/

    /** KMEANS **/

    /*
     * Starting from the last point in the dataset. A point is a candidate for a cluster if euclidian distance < threshold
     * and it is the closest cluster
     */

    while (chunk_size > 0) {
        chunk_size--;

        /*
         * Searching for the candidate cluster
         */

        temp = DBL_MAX;
        int candidate = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
            distance = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < dimension; ++j) {
                distance += pow(dataset[chunk_size].values[j] - discard_set[i].values[j], 2);
            }

            if (sqrt(distance) < temp && sqrt(distance) < threshold) {
                temp = distance;
                candidate = i;
            }
        }


        /*
         * If candidate > -1 then the point can be assigned to a cluster (the candidate)
         * else (candidate = -1) the point must be moved to retained set
         * 
         */


        if (candidate > -1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
                discard_set[candidate].values[i] = ((discard_set[candidate].values[i] * discard_set[candidate].n_tot) +
                                                    dataset[chunk_size].values[i]) / (discard_set[candidate].n_tot + 1);
                discard_set[candidate].values[i + dimension] =
                        ((discard_set[candidate].values[i + dimension] * discard_set[candidate].n_tot) +
                         pow(dataset[chunk_size].values[i], 2)) / (discard_set[candidate].n_tot + 1);
            }

            discard_set[candidate].n_tot++;
            discard_set[candidate].n_act++;

            discard_set[candidate].ids = realloc(discard_set[candidate].ids,
                                                 discard_set[candidate].n_act * sizeof(int));
            if (!discard_set[candidate].ids)
                exit(12);

            discard_set[candidate].ids[discard_set[candidate].n_act - 1] = dataset[chunk_size].id;

        } else {
            pinr++;
            retained_set = realloc(retained_set, pinr * sizeof(struct point));
            if (!retained_set)
                exit(-2);
            memcpy(retained_set + pinr - 1, dataset + chunk_size, sizeof(struct point));

        }
        dataset = realloc(dataset, chunk_size * sizeof(struct point));
    }
    /** ------END------- **/
    return 0;
}
```

I'm developing a clustering algorithm. After initializing the cluster, if a point belongs to a cluster it must be added to that cluster, if it doesn't belong to any cluster it is added to the retained set (outlier).

The problem is that when k-means starts I have a strange behaviour with pointer `discard_set->values`, it changes arbitrary the value. i.e. for example: in an iteration `candidate == 1`, for some reason sometimes it will change also values in `discard_set[2].values`.

After compiling I execute it with these parameters: `"db.csv" 3 3 1 10`
Here's the [db.csv](https://mega.nz/file/9DERSKYb#XHgJTH-4lrjXfs7-PQvepZB_8drQHfsHH5bkJ-ut-dA).

It is required to remove pointer that have be added to a cluster and to maintain in memory only outlier.
I hope to be clear.

edit: sometimes instead of change values in `discard_set->values`, `dataset->values` are changed

edit: I changed the chunk reading as follow:

```
while ((getline(&line, &len, file)) != -1 && idx < chunk_size) {
        if (idx > -1) { //Ovvero salto la riga di intestazione
            char *copy = line;
            while ((token = strsep(&copy, ","))) {
                if (elem_idx == -1) //è l'id del punto
                    dataset[idx].id = atoi(token);
                else if (elem_idx < dimension) //sono i dati del punto
                    dataset[idx].values[elem_idx] = atof(token);
                else
                    exit(14);
                elem_idx++;
            }
            elem_idx = -1;
            idx++;
        } else
            idx++;
    }
```

Comment: <https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example>

Comment: There is too much code, start reducing the amoun to a [mre].

Comment: I posted the complete code because I don't understand where is the problem and I think it is necessary this to let someone help me. It isn't the complete project but just a part of it

Answer (score 0):

[`strsep(&line, ",")` changes the value in `line`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html), which means it no longer points to a value obtained from `malloc()`:

> If `*stringp` is `NULL`, the `strsep()` function returns `NULL` and does
> nothing else.  Otherwise, this function finds the first token in
> the string `*stringp`, that is delimited by one of the bytes in the
> string `delim`.  This token is terminated by overwriting the
> delimiter with a null byte (`'\0'`), **and `*stringp` is updated to
> point past the token.**  ...

Per [the POSIX `getline()` documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/getline.html):

> ...
>
> The application shall ensure that `*lineptr` is a valid argument that could be passed to the `free()` function. ...

By modifying `line` with `strsep()`, you're corrupting your heap.  What's likely happening is the modified `line` value refers deep into the original allocation that `line` referred to, so when `getline()` uses `len` bytes from the updated `line` value it overruns the buffer, obliterating portions of the heap.

**You must not change the value used by `getline()` in your code.**

Use `strsep()` on a *copy* of that value:

```
while ((getline(&line, &len, file)) != -1 && idx < chunk_size) {
    if (idx > -1) { //Ovvero salto la riga di intestazione
        char *copy = line;
        while ((token = strsep(&copy, ","))) {
            if (elem_idx == -1) //è l'id del punto
```

Comment: The problem still exist, some values in `dataset->values`   are arbitrary changed. Edit: also `discard_set->values` are changed

Comment: @LucaMarchio  There are other possible issues that are dependent on run-time values.  Your code doesn't ensure that `elem_idx < dimension`, for example.  So if a line has too many elements, the code will again overrun a *different* array.

Comment: But it can't be bigger than `dimension`, when all the elements in a line are assigned to values, `elem_idx` is set to -1. I think it is not the problem

Comment: And more, I check if after reading the data `dataset` is right filled, and it is always, after, when k-means section start, something strange occurs and it changes values that should not be changed

Comment: @LucaMarchio *But it can't be bigger than `dimension`* Yes, it can. You haven't provided samples of your input data.  And note that `atoi()` has no way to return any error condition. Nothing in your code checks for nor prevents `elem_idx >= dimension`. Anywhere. Your code literally doesn't check anything when you're reading data - you just hope it all fits in what you've allocated.  You need to check every value for validity, and you need to check while you're actually reading that nothing goes out of range.  Right now, you don't know what's going on when you run your code.

Comment: (cont) And neither does anyone else because you haven't provided a complete example that can be tested.

Comment: I provide the CSV file from which I'm reading data, there is a link to Mega, and you can copy and paste the whole code, it is the complete code